# Is PayPal's Message Centre available via an API?

Tags: paypal

I am working on a project and my clients want to have the Message centre of Paypal integrated into their system so they won't need to log in every time on PayPal account to check their emails and reply.

I can not find any available option on their developer portal for a call similar to that. But I thought to ask here as may someone had better luck finding that.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [customer Disputes API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/disputes/) for handling that part of backend administration. This is typically only useful for large/enterprise merchants.

Other things require logging into the account. User logins with specific/limited roles [can be created.](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-add-users-to-my-paypal-account-faq1605)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already making use of the Dispute API but is not what I am looking for. The Message Centre has nothing to do with the Disputes as it's a direct communication between the Paypal account holder and Paypal itself (no customers involved) 

I had already suggested the different user creation but they were not pleased with that, so I thought to give it a go

Comment: Oh, yes Disputes uses the Resolution Center. For messaging PayPal, there is no API.